# how to extract the html and css used in this particular website www.bnchospital.edu.np?

Tags: html, css

www.bnchospital.edu.np , I need only the html and css for this website. using any software or anything just want the code of html and css

Comment: We do not encourage this kind of questions here. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Right click anywhere on the browser window and click "View page source" or anything similar. It will give you the code. Then just copy and paste the HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Ctrl + U and can get the HTML and css and js script.
You will get all required css and js